# Apache Cordova: Stay awake

Tags: javascript, html, apache-cordova

Is there a possibility in Apache Cordova and Javascript to tell the Phone to not go into sleep mode, while my app is visible?

I've found things like keepScreenOn, but this is Java-Code, which I don't have in Apache Cordova or at least I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: Depend on target platform ?  What platforms do you target?

Comment: Mainly Android, but if possible it would be nice to have it on all platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Insomnia](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin) plugin for Cordova.